# QPalette , set background image Python3 PyQT4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I am trying to set a background image to a QFrame I am calling in a QMainWindows like such :

```
        class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


        def initUI(self):


        #central widget
        self.theboard = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.theboard)




        class Board(QtGui.QFrame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initBoard()

        def initBoard(self):

        #Set background Image
         frame = Board
         palette = QPalette()
         palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("ImageTest.jpg"))) 
         frame.setPalette(palette)
```

Using Qpalette / Qpixmap as I have found on some exemple on the net. 
But it don't work :

self.palette = QPalette()
NameError: global name 'QPalette' is not defined

Why ? Here my class : class Board(QtGui.QFrame):

I am well inheriting of QtGui so Qpalette should work. 
I have to admit I am a bit confuse with the way Qpalette works.

Any help much apreciated,

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write it in your code, so perhaps your issue is you didn't import it.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette
```

If that isn't the case, try this:

```
palette = QPalette()
palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("anne.jpg"))) # Haha, aren't I so funny??
frame.setPalette(palette)
```

Comment: Hi, in deed I didn't write it just : import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui.
Since I imported QtGui I was expecting I didn't need to import anything from QtGui... I guess it will be the same with QBrush...

Comment: Just changed that bit : self.setPalette(self.palette) and put it at the end...
So no more error thank you, but still I cant display my image in background(my ImageTest is at the same root than my .py)...

Comment: Also try adding to the `from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette` line by typing `from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QPixmap, QBrush`. Keep in mind I use PyQt5 so this may not work.

Comment: It is exactly how I have imported once you remembered to do so : ) I can confirm it works well in pyQT4, I don't have any errors anymore, just I don't have anything displayed in my background. (Maybe I need to specifie the script to fit the image or something like that ? ) Difficult to put my whole program it is quite long but I will try to put a better snip of it that show more around the problematic bit as soon as I come back near it.

Comment: Also, in the references I have read QPalette.Background have been depreciated in favour of QPalette.Window ("QPalette.Background  This value is obsolete. Use Window instead.")    Don't say more unfortunately, could it be ?.

Comment: off topic but I can't find how to send a private message here. I can see in your profile you use PyGame, what do you think of it ?

Comment: I'll look into it for you and find an answer about the backgrounds. Pygame is excellent but has a steep learning curve so it can be a bit tricky sometimes and GUIs need extra toolkits. However it is worth learning!! :) Finally, [you can't send PM's to other users.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: Edited my Question with more details in my code. You can see my QFrame is the central widget of a QMainWindow.
*Shame for the MP, that is always useful! I will have a look on PyGame : ) Can't wait : )

Comment: Please include entire program, and gfy with Pygame :)

Comment: HA not enought of code still, I was rewriting a simpler version of my code for testing better and posting then I fell on an interesting error :
    frame.setPalette(palette)
TypeError: QWidget.setPalette(QPalette): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'

Comment: Looks like setPalette won't works on a QFrame, only a QWidget.